# Whats the simplest way to put a wildcard integer into a string?

Tags: python, python-2.7

For example if I have the code:

```
for row in self.reader:
    if row:
        if row[0] == "Stage * Disk Face":
            """CODE TO EXECUTE"""
```

However, is there a way to make the asterisk `*` any arbitrary number so that if it finds the string `"Stage 1 Disk Face"` or `"Stage 2 Disk Face"` or `"Stage 3 Disk Face"` etc., the code will execute? The reason is not every stage number will have a disk face feature. I basically need to find out if there's at least one, with any arbitrary number.

Comment: I would use regex on row[0]. If so you can use "\d+" as 'wildcard'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work:

```
import re

for row in self.reader:
    if row:
        if re.match('^Stage [0-9]+ Disk Face$', row[0]):
            """CODE TO EXECUTE"""
```

Comment: It will not catch "Stage x Disk Face" where x > 9. I would suggest using "[0-9]+"

Comment: `^` at the start, `$` at the end

Comment: `+` matches numbers between 0 and 9 between 1 and unlimited times

Comment: I know I am being pain in the ass but since OP asks for 'integer' following regex is better : "-?[0-9]+" :)

Answer (score 0):

Check this

```
# coding=utf8
# the above tag defines encoding for this document and is for Python 2.x compatibility

import re

regex = r"(Stage )[0-9]( Disk Face)"

test_str = "Stage 1 Disk Face"

matches = re.search(regex, test_str)

if matches:
    print ("Match was found at {start}-{end}: {match}".format(start = matches.start(), end = matches.end(), match = matches.group()))

    for groupNum in range(0, len(matches.groups())):
        groupNum = groupNum + 1

        print ("Group {groupNum} found at {start}-{end}: {group}".format(groupNum = groupNum, start = matches.start(groupNum), end = matches.end(groupNum), group = matches.group(groupNum)))

# Note: for Python 2.7 compatibility, use ur"" to prefix the regex and u"" to prefix the test string and substitutio
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import re

#if row[0] == "Stage * Disk Face":
if re.search(r'Stage \d Disk Face', row[0]):
    pass
```

Answer (score 0):

It would be easiest just to use a regex:

```
import re

rows = [["Stage 1 Disk Face"], ["Stage 2 Disk Face"], ["Stage 3 Disk Face"]]
pattern = re.compile("Stage .* Disk Face")

for row in rows:
    if row:
        if pattern.match(row[0]):
            print(row[0])
```